# Is the sentence used by this person grammatically correct?

Tags: sentence-meaning, grammaticality

"You need a closet to store all that attitude of yours."

So, I was scrolling through facebook and I came across this comment made by some person. And I kept thinking about whether it was grammatically correct. Oh, and the person the comment was intended for was a really arrogant person.
So, what does the sentence mean? Is it grammatically correct?

Comment: It might help if you explained _why_ you think this sentence might not be grammatically correct.

Comment: **all that attitude** is idiomatic AmE to be sure. Often pronounced AT-eee-tood  (rhyming with food, the middle syllable rhyming with 'bee' as in bumblebee).

Comment: @TRomano - I'm confused.  What's particularly idiomatic about "all that attitude" as opposed to, say, "all that (any other mass noun)"?  And where have you heard people pronounce it like that?

Comment: @standgon: There's nothing "particularly" idiomatic about it. Is **attitude** a "mass" noun? I can give you a handful of clay but not a handful of attitude. Pronunciation: https://mycitypaper.com/articles/081497/article008.shtml

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I believe it is grammatical.

> [attitude](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/attitude)
>
> 7. **a** :  a negative or hostile state of mind
>      **b** :  a cool, cocky, defiant, or arrogant manner

If *attitude* were physical, tangible, then this person has so much of it that he/she would need a closet in which to store it all. It's meant to be an insulting comment.